# jboss 7.1, What is standalone.log

Tags: jboss

I would like to know what is the purpose of bin\standalone.log at windows server 2008 R2.

When I compare standalone.log whit log\server.log I see the same content.

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running as a service it might just be the piped stdout. If you're not running from a console you could remove the console handler which would limit the output.

Assuming the default configuration you could use the following CLI command to remove the handler.

```
/subsystem=logging/logging=root-logger:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```